# Annotate a Python function so that it narrows down the return type of an union involving a typevar

Tags: python, mypy, type-hinting, python-typing

I'm currently in the process of adding type annotations for a medium-sized library. The library has some quite complex cases that I would like to handle. I managed to simplify these complex cases to the following, much easier, one.

Consider the following *pseudo-identity* function:

```py
def g(x, y): return x, y
```

Let's assume that this function accepts either two parameters of the same type (TL;DR: any pair of objects of the same type implementing the `Comparable` protocol I defined but let's consider subclasses of `int` for this example) **OR** a special string literal (for this example, let's simply consider a `str`). To summarize, these calls are valid: `g(1, 2)`, `g('hi', 'world')`, `g(1, 'world')`, etc. but these calls aren't: `g({}, 3)`, `g([], True)`, etc.

I'm looking for a way to annotate this function so that the return type can be deduced by mypy precisely. For instance, I'm expecting `g(1,2)` to lead to a tuple of ints, `g('hi', 'world')` to a tuple of `str`, `g(1, 'world')` to `tuple[int, str]`, and the invalid cases would lead to an error.

Naively, I wrote:

```py
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T', bound=int)

def g(x: T | str, y: T | str) -> tuple[T | str, T | str]:
    return x, y
```

AFAIK, this should be enough to ensure that both parameters have the same type (and are instances of int) OR that one (or both) of them is/are str.

However, when I execute mypy on this snippet as follows:

```py
reveal_type(g(3, 4))
reveal_type(g('hello', 'world'))
reveal_type(g('hello', 2))
```

I got this output:

```
main.py:8: note: Revealed type is "tuple[Union[builtins.int, builtins.str], Union[builtins.int, builtins.str]]"
main.py:9: note: Revealed type is "tuple[builtins.str, builtins.str]"
main.py:10: note: Revealed type is "tuple[Union[builtins.int, builtins.str], Union[builtins.int, builtins.str]]"
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

You can see this live in mypy Playground: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=a5063b88271ddd94a58c82e3376deb5c

The second line is what I expected (a tuple of strings), but the two other calls *should* (or *could*) be refined to `tuple[int, int]` and `tuple[str, int]`. The result is similar with PyRight, and merely similar with Pyre (the latter indicates `tuple[str, Literal[2]]` instead of `tuple[str, int]` for the last case, for some unknown reason).

Is this something out of scope of the `typing` module or out of scope of mypy? Am I missing something?

Notice that I **cannot** write `T = TypeVar('T', int, str)`. While this works (for the above example), remember that I used `int` to simplify the case, where in practice I want `T` to be any class implementing my `Comparable` protocol (so I need to define `T` with an upper bound, not with a list of exact types, this is, `T = TypeVar('T', bound=Comparable)`).

---

To put some more context for this question (do not read if you don't care ;-), the library I want to annotate defines an `Interval` class made of two bounds (the lower and upper ones). These bounds can be any object that supports comparison (e.g., ints, floats, dates). To handle infinite and semi-infinite intervals, the library defines a two special objects, namely `inf` and `-inf` that are respectively singleton instances of `_PInf` and `_NInf`. My goal is to annotate this `Interval` class so that mypy can check whether `Interval(x, y)` is valid (i.e., `x` and `y` are of the same `Comparable` type, or `x` or `y` or both are instances of `_PInf` `_NInf`).

Generalizing the above example, I currently have something like this:

```py
Comparable = ...  # Protocol with __eq__, __lt__, __le__, ...
T = TypeVar('T', bound=Comparable)
Bound: TypeAlias = T | _PInf | _NInf

class Interval(Generic[T]):
  def __init__(self, lower: Bound[T], upper: Bound[T]) -> None:
    ...
```

The goal is (1) to make sure that both bounds are "compatible" (as explained in previous paragraph), and (2) that, for example, `Interval(1, 2).lower + 1` does not trigger any complaint from mypy, while `Interval(-inf, 2).lower + 1` does.

Comment: Can `lower` actually be `_PInf`?

Comment: @insync yes, even if it sounds counter intuitive. We represent empty intervals as (inf, - inf).

Comment: @InSync: To clarify, the answer is "no": it cannot be `_PInf` (the class) but can be `_PInf()`, a (singleton) instance of this class. An empty interval is consistently encoded as `(_PInf(), _NInf())`. That said, this "detail" is not really relevant I think, but if it helps, infinities can not only be considered as instances of `_PInf` and `_NInf` but also as literals, except they cannot be used with `typing.Literal` (only accepts str, int, etc.)  ;-)

Comment: I should have said "...be *of type* `_PInf`". You should make them `Enum` members, since `Literal` can work with that.

Comment: They are singleton objects, so the benefit of using an Enum is low. The public API does not even expose `_PInf` and `_NInf` (and they are not really used internally). We defined `inf = _PInf()` and only `inf` is exposed (and use consistently). Since `_PInf` defines `__neg__` to return a `_NInf` singleton, `inf` can be used anywhere for positive infinities, and `-inf` anywhere for negative infinities. That said, the exact nature of `_PInf` is not going to affect much how to annotate types in the situation described in the question, if I'm right.

Comment: The last example is confusing. That doesn't seem to be a problem with `Interval`, but rather with the assumption that something of type `Bound[T]` supports addition.

Comment: I (probably wrongly) thought that if an "int" is passed for "lower", then static type checkers "remember" that the variable is an int (i.e., it narrows Bound[T] to int), so it wouldn't be a problem to use addition on it. I couldn't try this assumption (and already have some ideas to circumvent this), since so far I cannot even make the simpler example work ;-)

Comment: Mypy behavior is correct here - you do not express such "narrowing" in the signature. Something like this should better represent your use case: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=f4e516e87a360dd7316130c25a4dbd46

Comment: Though it doesn't help with your "generalized" example - I'm not sure that one is doable in python's type system, unless you are okay with using two generic params (one per each end).

Comment: (skeleton of what I mean by two variables with some overloads missing: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=8cbc578333e7bfcbe9bacef316574f84)

Comment: @STerliakov Am I missing something or the overloads can be written as, for example, [`def g(a: str, b: T) -> tuple[str, T]`](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=24d390eab760e4453184457144746673) instead of `def g(a: T | str, b: T) -> tuple[T | str, T]`?

Comment: @InSync nope. It looks correct on the first glance, until you have `x: int | str`. In such case `g(x, 0)` will be inferred as `tuple[str|int, str|int]`, the right bound will not be as narrow as OP wants.

Comment: @Guybrush did this work for you? I finally got some time to write an answer; if not - what's missing or failing?

Comment: @STerliakov: The "trick" using `@overload` works well for the "toy" example, but I couldn't generalize it to my use case, likely for the same reasons you thought about in another comment. Basically, having only one generic is not enough to "keep track" of the bounds (in presence of infinities) and relying on 2 generics solves mypy's complaints but doesn't help to ensure the two types are "compatible" (i.e., T and U are the same type or infinities). I wrote down my "expectations" and I think there are over what Python's typing can handle right now (it seems I'll need f-bounded polymorphism).

Comment: That said, I think I'll "type-annotate" my library in a very naive way (i.e., returning `Interval` instances, without any parametrization) at first, and see how I can "fine-tune" the annotations if needed. The "generic" aspect I put into this library is perhaps/likely not something that can be handled by a type system. Sometimes, I forgot that I love Python because it is mostly about "duck typing" rather than "strict" typing ;-) FYI, the library I talked about is portion (https://github.com/AlexandreDecan/portion) :)